# Access 'final' modifier class in java

Tags: java, final, access-modifiers

How to access a 'final' modifier class in java? I tried to create an object of that class but it is not accepting. Can anybody tell me that how to initialize or call that class in my own java class.

For example I want to use this class in my own class http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/internal/telephony/CallManager.java.html

Thx in advance

Comment: It is very hard to understand what you are asking about. Can you provide an example of code that doesn't work for you?

Comment: Define "access"? You cannot extend final classes if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using an `enum` This creates a final class with a private constructor and all instances are public static final by default.

Comment: @Mathias: I linked on class. plz check it. It is an 'final' modifier class. How to access this class in my own class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the `CallManager` you linked, simply do the following in your code:

```
CallManager manager = CallManager.getInstance();
```

All public methods defined on the manager will then be available for you to use.

Comment: Hi mcfinnigan, I called CallManger.java class as u mentioned above. But still I am getting null value.

Answer (score 3):

Final modifier is not related to possibility of instantiating.

Check whether the constructor of the class you need is visible.

Maybe you should read some information about Java basics? Almost all you questions are related to topics are described on the first pages of any book about Java.

Answer (score 2):

`final` classes means it `can't be extended`. That's not your problem. Your problem is the `constructor` that is `private`, but the `CallManager` provides a getter for the instance:

```
CallManager callManager = CallManager.getInstance();
```